# Как хранить правильно переносы \n в БД, чтобы python их воспринимал?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

При выборке предложений из БД, где используется `\n` для переноса строки, \n воспринимается, как просто два символа.

Если же вписать \n в код вручную , как обычно, то работает исправно.

Пример:

В столбце Vote в таблице Ex в БД хранится:

```
\nВарианты ответа:\n**A.** Traveled\n**B.** Traveling\n**C.** Travel\n**D.** Travels
```

Выборка и вставка в переменные для вывода:

```
    cur.execute("""SELECT Vote FROM Ex""")
    mess = cur.fetchone()

    await ctx.send(f"{mess[2]}")
```

На выходе получаю: `\nВарианты ответа:\nA. Traveled\nB. Traveling\nC. Travel\nD. Travels`

Вывожу сообщения в discord, но это к делу не имеет отношения.

**Как хранить правильно переносы в БД, чтобы python их воспринимал?**

Comment: Сделайте print, в каком виде из базы данные приходят.

Comment: Боюсь, что Вы добавляете `\\n` что отображается как `\n`..

Comment: То, что указал на выходе и есть print. 
Насчёт \\n не совсем понял, ибо в БД хранятся просто \n

Comment: Пока что получилось исправить только так: .replace(r"\n", "\n")

Comment: как Вы туда `\n` записывали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Символы `\n` хранятся как обычные символы, а не как управляющие символы, обозначающие перенос строки.

При выборке из БД, `\n` воспринимаются просто как два символа, а не как перенос строки.

Проблему удалось решить с помощью функции **replace()**.

Пример решения:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):

        cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM Ex""")
        
        f1 = cur.fetchall()
        f2= f1[0][2].replace(r"\n", "\n")

await ctx.send(f"Строка с переменной, где хранится текст с переносом строки {f2}"
```

Comment: Всё это означает, что вы накосячили при записи данных в БД (или не вы, а кто-то другой, кто записывал туда данные)

Comment: Я поэтому и задавал вопрос, как необходимо правильно хранить такие данные. Я не знаю и не нашёл способа, как хранить перенос строки в базе данных, чтобы затем python воспринимал это именно как перенос строки, а не просто символы.

Comment: Простое `INSERT INTO таблица VALUES('бла\nбла')` запишет всё правильно

Comment: С учётом использования python в нём это могло бы выглядеть примерно как `cur.execute('INSERT INTO таблица VALUES(?)', ('бла\nбла',))`

Comment: Действительно. Я для удобства вносил вручную в SQLite studio, ожидая того же. Глупо с моей стороны. Спасибо за помощь! Не ожидал настолько банального решения. Можете написать ответом, я укажу, как решение, если хотите